# How can I authenticate apollo with Auth0 in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apollo, auth0, hasura

I am struggling with [a tutorial from Hasura](https://hasura.io/blog/add-authentication-and-authorization-to-vue-js-apps-with-auth0-graphql/) which I believe might never have worked. I think it might be missing a piece and I'm interested in the most appropriate way to bridge the gap between when I've created and what will work.

From that documentation, as well as the [Auth0 VueJS documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login#) I have been able to create a working VueJS application that authenticates via my Auth0 project and gives me back a user profile complete with user photo and email. So that's all working.

Following the Hausura tutorial from this I added apollo. I am now able to access non-protected GraphQL queries from my API but not protected ones. The reason is pretty clearly the code I added from the tutorial here:

```
  getAuth: () => {
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    const token = localStorage.getItem('apollo-token')
    if (token) {
      return 'Bearer ' + token
    } else {
      return ''
    }   
  },
```

A `console.log` shows that `token` is `null` even when I'm logged in. It's pretty obvious why too. localStorage was never updated to contain  a token. So of course it's null. There's no place in the tutorial that suggests this should be set anywhere but clearly it should.

So I did some digging and in that file `src/vue-apollo.js` there is an `onLogin` and `onLogout` function which require an ApolloClient object and in the case of the login, also a token. This will set the local storage appropriately.

Currently, my login is done within `src/view/Home.vue` like so:

```
login() {
   this.$auth.loginWithRedirect()
   // ... maybe do something here ?
},
```

Now if I were to add something like this after the login, it will not actually be called because of the redirect. But I think I need to add something like this:

```
this.$auth.getTokenSilently(token => {
  onLogin(this.$apolloProvider.defaultClient, token)
}
```

Perhaps I need to add this into like the `mounted()` or `beforeCreate()` live cycle hook in my `src/App.vue`? I'm really not sure how to proceed here. Does this tutorial even really work?

Furthermore, isn't storing an auth token in localStorage a bad idea because of cross site request forgery?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about it not being detailed in the post. I've not run the project but following the link to the source code of the demo. The `/callback` route creates the key via Callback component at `/app/src/router.js:25`, it add an authentication guard as well.

Then on `/app/src/components/Callback.vue:25` on created `handleAuthentication` from auth service is called.

```js
  created() {
    this.$auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
```

You can check the code in `/app/src/auth/authService.js` it uses the auth0 library instance to get the token and call `localLogin` that saves the token in line 92.

About the security, I would follow the advice in [Token Storage](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/token-storage) from Auth0.